# Elastic Search search related

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say we have the following 3 documents stored in an ES `Type`:

Document 1:

```
{
  foo: [
    "c"
  ],
  bar: "bar1"
}
```

Document 2:

```
{
  foo: [
    "a"
    "b"
  ],
  bar: "bar2"
}
```

Document 3:

```
{
  foo: [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c"
  ],
  bar: "bar3"
}
```

I want to do a search in ES such that given the input `foo: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`, the result should return only Document 3. This is basically saying, find that single document which has the max number of entries in the `foo` array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use should and size is 1 so ideally the document 3 got high relevance and should be in the top. and size 1 will return the most relevant document

```
"size" : 1,
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "term": {"foo": "a"}},
        { "term": {"foo": "b"}},
        { "term": {"foo": "c"}},
        { "term": {"foo": "d"}},
      ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for the query. works like a charm. How can i accept your answer? cant seem to find the button